# Is writing unions content to file safe

Tags: c, struct, portability, unions, vm-implementation

I am developing simple virtual machine in C, and it will use Threaded code, consider this structure:

```
struct opcode
{
  int somefields; //etc
  union z
  {
    char opcode;
    void *opaddress;
  }
}
```

my question is, is't safe and portable to write such struct with char data (opcode) and load that file on another machine (and maybe different architecture) and fill the pointer (opaddress) on the fly?

Comment: The size of the union may vary on different architectures, so copying all of its bytes may fail simply because you write too many bytes on a machine with shorter pointers. It would be easier to simply write and read the `char` `opcode`.

Comment: Well no. There is no standard for padding that may or may not exist. So a `write` on one machine does not guarantee an equivalent `read` of the struct on another compiler. The bytes will be the same, but whether it is loaded into the same `struct`? It gets better when you consider `(void*`) , e.g. a pointer, may be of different sizes in different architectures. A pointer and a `char` are surely never the same size. I'm sure there other considerations. There are also serialization libraries to insure you can do something similar to this.

Comment: Friends,  please note that when I write to the file I'll never write any pointers (void *) instead I'll write char value then when I read the data from the file then maybe I will write the pointer on the fly in the union according to the value of the char.

Comment: It really all boils down to this. If you write `s.somefields` and then write `s.opcode` and then read `s.somefields` and then `s.opcode`, there is no problem. If you `fwrite (const ptr_to_struct, sizeof *ptr_to_struct, 1, file)` then moving the file and recompiling on another computer and attempting to `fread (ptr_to_struct, sizeof *ptr_to_struct, 1, file)` is not guaranteed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin , so you are suggesting to write opcode characters (and some field) in some format without writing the whole structure into the file? this will make it portable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you have and `int` and a `char`, just write an `int` and `char` to file, then on whatever machine you move to, you can always recompile and read the `int` and `char` into your struct/union without having to worry about differences in padding or alignment between compilers and architectures (as long as `int` is the same size for all)

Comment: That's good, I think I'll take this route. Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

The data types will vary between different architecture, so you can't guarantee the same size.

```
typedef struct 
{
  int somefields; //etc
  union 
  {
    char opcode;
    void *opaddress;
  }z;
}opc;
```

you can access something like this

```
opc.somefields = 10;
opc.z.opcode = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.